Is there a native "reveal password" feature for `<input type="password" />` in Chrome?
The following HTML code, when rendered in Edge (Windows), displays a "reveal password" button within the field:
Password: <input type="password" />


However, the same is not happening in Chrome:

Is there some way to enable this behavior for our users (perhaps via some HTML attribute or a CSS rule)? Or the only way to have this functionality working cross-browser is still to develop it ourselves?
I guess the "reveal button" was Edge's original feature. But I found some old sources saying that the feature was coming to other Chromium browsers, too:

Universal "reveal password" button is now available in Chrome Canary (dated 2019)
Chrome and Edge will soon reveal typed passwords with a click of a button (dated 2020)

... but it's 5 years later, and such feature doesn't seem enabled by default in Chrome. Does anyone know if it was ever released to stable builds of Chrome? Maybe it's not enabled by default but there is some way to enable it for certain fields?

Don't forget that other browsers may also not have a "reveal password" button. It's not all about Chrome, there are other browsers out there too. Don't forget that Chrome isn't always Chrome either (looking at you Apple)!

"Or the only way to have this functionality working cross-browser is still to develop it ourselves?" At present, yes.

@phuzi Sure, I just wanted to limit the scope of a question by making it more specific :) I'm interested in other browsers too, and ideally in some HTML standard allowing to enable it (if it exists)

There's nothing about this in the current spec. See also the MDN documentation for password inputs

TL:DR; You're (currently) going to have to implement this yourself.
There's not much in the specification about how the password input should be rendered beyond obscuring the value (emphasis mine):

The input element represents a one line plain text edit control for the element's value. The user agent should obscure the value so that people other than the user cannot see it.

The method of obscuring the password is not specified either
